# Calling a button click with ExtNet confirm message

Tags: javascript, c#, ext.net

I want to call a button click function by using a ExtNet Confirm message.

At first this was a normal button with a normal click but now we want to add a condition and confirmation to it. Has to be extnet.

What we want to do is; If the user clicks yes, data gets saved and button works as normal. If clicked no, only the button works

ExtNet Confirm message

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            X.Msg.Confirm("Warning", "Message", new JFunction { Fn = "Save" }).Show();
        }
```

and the javascript part

```
var Save = function (btn) {
            Ext.Msg.notify("Button Click", "You clicked the " + btn + " button");
        }
```

I know the message is the example on extnet documentaries. Using it to see if it's working.

and the button

```
protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//it's assignments and other functions.
}
```

I just have no idea how to trigger the button click function. I came across a few similar questions but they were no help and I have no experience on Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a c# event from javascript using ext.net you can use what they call DirectEvents, check this example from their website:

http://examples.ext.net/#/Events/DirectEvents/Overview/

The "Add a <Click> DirectEvent with confirmation to <ext:Button>" is what you need.